# PHP Mocking Final Class

Tags: php, unit-testing, doctrine-orm, mocking, phpunit

I am attempting to mock a php `final class` but since it is declared `final` I keep receiving this error:

`PHPUnit_Framework_Exception: Class "Doctrine\ORM\Query" is declared "final" and cannot be mocked.`

Is there anyway to get around this `final` behavior just for my unit tests without introducing any new frameworks?

Comment: You could create a copy of the FINAL class that isn't FINAL and mock it

Comment: @BryantFrankford thanks for the solution. While this would work, ideally I would prefer to avoid writing a new class for this specific situation. You wouldn't happen to be aware of a solution that would scale a little better?
If this becomes gating to my project then I will implement the above solution

Comment: Other than changing the original class to not be final, I personally don't have any other solution.

Comment: Consider trying phpunit's prophecy interface:  https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html#test-doubles.prophecy.  It's a bit different and does not care about finals and such.

Comment: can you write an unit test to be done, as example?

Comment: I tried using prophecy, but it seems to have the same limitation with the final classes : `Class "Symfony\Component\Cache\CacheItem" is declared "final" and cannot be mocked.`

Comment: @cerad Prophecy can't either mock final classes.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Since you mentioned you don't want to use any other framework, you are only leaving yourself one option: [uopz](http://php.net/uopz)

uopz is a black magic extension of the runkit-and-scary-stuff genre, intended to help with QA infrastructure.

[uopz_flags](http://php.net/uopz_flags) is a function that can modify the flags of functions, methods and classes.

```
<?php
final class Test {}

/** ZEND_ACC_CLASS is defined as 0, just looks nicer ... **/

uopz_flags(Test::class, null, ZEND_ACC_CLASS);

$reflector = new ReflectionClass(Test::class);

var_dump($reflector->isFinal());
?>
```

Will yield

```
bool(false)
```

Answer (score 20):

For someone who is looking for this specific doctrine query mock answer.

You can not mock Doctrine\ORM\Query because of its "final" declaration, but if you look into Query class code then you will see that it's extending AbstractQuery class and there should not be any problems mocking it.

```
/** @var \PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_MockObject|AbstractQuery $queryMock */
$queryMock = $this
    ->getMockBuilder('Doctrine\ORM\AbstractQuery')
    ->disableOriginalConstructor()
    ->setMethods(['getResult'])
    ->getMockForAbstractClass();
```

**Updates**: Actually the method `setMethods()` is deprecated, because it don't check the existence of the method, so you could delete the real method and still pass the test. Instead you can use addMethods()

Comment: This works for a class marked final that extend an abstract or implement an interface. If the class itself is being defined final then you'll have to use one of the other work-a-rounds.

Comment: Much cleaner compared to all the others. +1

Comment: This solution looks pretty good, but I'm trying to get it to work with codeception, and finding this error when I call 'getResult':

 Trying to configure method "getResult" which cannot be configured because it does not exist, has not been specified, is final, or is static

Comment: After a little more digging - using 'execute' rather than 'getResult' allowed this to work!

Answer (score 14):

There is a small library [Bypass Finals](https://github.com/dg/bypass-finals) exactly for such purpose. Described in detail by [blog post](https://phpfashion.com/how-to-mock-final-classes).

Only you have to do is enable this utility before classes are loaded:

```
DG\BypassFinals::enable();
```

Comment: Is there any alternative for php 5.5?

Comment: The tool itself works with PHP 5.4 today. You can download the `BypassFinals.php`, the only required file, and include it.

Comment: There's a more indepth article available here: https://tomasvotruba.com/blog/2019/03/28/how-to-mock-final-classes-in-phpunit/

Answer (score 12):

When you want to mock a final class, its a perfect moment to make use of [Dependency inversion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle):

> One should depend upon abstractions, not concretions.

For the mocking it means: Create an abstraction (interface or abstract class) and assign it to the final class, and mock the abstraction.

Comment: OK, but if the final class belongs to third party library, you cannot just simply edit it.
What I found out however: if you create an interface in your code, and the final class just _happens to implement it_ - i.e. it has the same method signatures but no `implements` keyword, it will still work :)

Comment: In this case you should adapt. Create an new interface in your project that will be your mockable dependency instead of the 3rd party dependency. The implementation of the new interface will then inject the unmockable 3rd party dependency. The implementation should not have any logic, only act as gateway to the 3rd party class methods, that is not worth to unit test.

Comment: Well, I must retract what I just said. The tests are passing, yes, but just because I injected what I wanted and made assertions that rely on it. However, application is not working anymore, because of error: method should return instance of my interface, but it just got instance of said final class instead. So it looks the `implements` keyword is necessary.
In this situation your proposed solution seems to be the only sensible way. Thank you :)

Answer (score 10):

I suggest you to take a look at the [mockery testing framework](http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/index.html) that have a workaround for this situation described in the page: [Dealing with Final Classes/Methods](http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/reference/final_methods_classes.html):

> You can create a proxy mock by passing the instantiated object you
>   wish to mock into \Mockery::mock(), i.e. Mockery will then generate a
>   Proxy to the real object and selectively intercept method calls for
>   the purposes of setting and meeting expectations.

As example this permit to do something like this:

```
class MockFinalClassTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    public function testMock()
    {
        $em = \Mockery::mock("Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager");

        $query = new Doctrine\ORM\Query($em);
        $proxy = \Mockery::mock($query);
        $this->assertNotNull($proxy);

        $proxy->setMaxResults(4);
        $this->assertEquals(4, $query->getMaxResults());
    }
```

I don't know what you need to do but, i hope this help

Comment: When the mocking class has final dependencies that has final dependencies its getting a mess. It seems only useful for final classes that has no dependencies.

Answer (score 10):

### 2019 answer for PHPUnit

I see you're using PHPUnit. You can use [bypass finals from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50796273/1348344).

The setup is just a bit more than `bootstrap.php`. Read "why" in [*How to Mock Final Classes in PHPUnit*](https://www.tomasvotruba.cz/blog/2019/03/28/how-to-mock-final-classes-in-phpunit/).

Here is "how" ↓

### 2 Steps

You need to use Hook with bypass call:

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

use DG\BypassFinals;
use PHPUnit\Runner\BeforeTestHook;

final class BypassFinalHook implements BeforeTestHook
{
    public function executeBeforeTest(string $test): void
    {
        BypassFinals::enable();
    }
}
```

Update `phpunit.xml`:

```
<phpunit bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php">
    <extensions>
        <extension class="Hook\BypassFinalHook"/>
    </extensions>
</phpunit>
```

Then you **can mock any final class**:

[image]

Comment: DG\BypassFinals utilizes `stream_wrapper_register`. This could prevent tools (f.e. Infection) relying on the same mechanism from working correctly.

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled upon the same problem with `Doctrine\ORM\Query`. I needed to unit test the following code:

```
public function someFunction()
{
    // EntityManager was injected in the class 
    $query = $this->entityManager
        ->createQuery('SELECT t FROM Test t')
        ->setMaxResults(1);

    $result = $query->getOneOrNullResult();

    ...

}
```

`createQuery` returns `Doctrine\ORM\Query` object. I couldn't use `Doctrine\ORM\AbstractQuery` for my mock because it doesn't have `setMaxResults` method and I didn't want to introduce any other frameworks.
To overcome the `final` restriction on the class I use [anonymous classes](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.anonymous.php) in PHP 7, which are super easy to create. In my test case class I have:

```
private function getMockDoctrineQuery($result)
{
    $query = new class($result) extends AbstractQuery {

        private $result;

        /**
         * Overriding original constructor.
         */
        public function __construct($result)
        {
            $this->result = $result;
        }

        /**
         * Overriding setMaxResults
         */
        public function setMaxResults($maxResults)
        {
            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Overriding getOneOrNullResult
         */
        public function getOneOrNullResult($hydrationMode = null)
        {
            return $this->result;
        }

        /**
         * Defining blank abstract method to fulfill AbstractQuery 
         */ 
        public function getSQL(){}

        /**
         * Defining blank abstract method to fulfill AbstractQuery
         */ 
        protected function _doExecute(){}
    };

    return $query;
}
```

Then in my test:

```
public function testSomeFunction()
{
    // Mocking doctrine Query object
    $result = new \stdClass;
    $mockQuery = $this->getMockQuery($result);

    // Mocking EntityManager
    $entityManager = $this->getMockBuilder(EntityManagerInterface::class)->getMock();
    $entityManager->method('createQuery')->willReturn($mockQuery);

    ...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Funny way :)

PHP7.1, PHPUnit5.7

```
<?php
use Doctrine\ORM\Query;

//...

$originalQuery      = new Query($em);
$allOriginalMethods = get_class_methods($originalQuery);

// some "unmockable" methods will be skipped
$skipMethods = [
    '__construct',
    'staticProxyConstructor',
    '__get',
    '__set',
    '__isset',
    '__unset',
    '__clone',
    '__sleep',
    '__wakeup',
    'setProxyInitializer',
    'getProxyInitializer',
    'initializeProxy',
    'isProxyInitialized',
    'getWrappedValueHolderValue',
    'create',
];

// list of all methods of Query object
$originalMethods = [];
foreach ($allOriginalMethods as $method) {
    if (!in_array($method, $skipMethods)) {
        $originalMethods[] = $method;
    }
}

// Very dummy mock
$queryMock = $this
    ->getMockBuilder(\stdClass::class)
    ->setMethods($originalMethods)
    ->getMock()
;

foreach ($originalMethods as $method) {

    // skip "unmockable"
    if (in_array($method, $skipMethods)) {
        continue;
    }

    // mock methods you need to be mocked
    if ('getResult' == $method) {
        $queryMock->expects($this->any())
            ->method($method)
            ->will($this->returnCallback(
                function (...$args) {
                    return [];
                }
            )
        );
        continue;
    }

    // make proxy call to rest of the methods
    $queryMock->expects($this->any())
        ->method($method)
        ->will($this->returnCallback(
            function (...$args) use ($originalQuery, $method, $queryMock) {
                $ret = call_user_func_array([$originalQuery, $method], $args);

                // mocking "return $this;" from inside $originalQuery
                if (is_object($ret) && get_class($ret) == get_class($originalQuery)) {
                    if (spl_object_hash($originalQuery) == spl_object_hash($ret)) {
                        return $queryMock;
                    }

                    throw new \Exception(
                        sprintf(
                            'Object [%s] of class [%s] returned clone of itself from method [%s]. Not supported.',
                            spl_object_hash($originalQuery),
                            get_class($originalQuery),
                            $method
                        )
                    );
                }

                return $ret;
            }
        ))
    ;
}


return $queryMock;
```

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented @Vadym approach and updated it. Now I use it for testing successfully!

```
protected function getFinalMock($originalObject)
{
    if (gettype($originalObject) !== 'object') {
        throw new \Exception('Argument must be an object');
    }

    $allOriginalMethods = get_class_methods($originalObject);

    // some "unmockable" methods will be skipped
    $skipMethods = [
        '__construct',
        'staticProxyConstructor',
        '__get',
        '__set',
        '__isset',
        '__unset',
        '__clone',
        '__sleep',
        '__wakeup',
        'setProxyInitializer',
        'getProxyInitializer',
        'initializeProxy',
        'isProxyInitialized',
        'getWrappedValueHolderValue',
        'create',
    ];

    // list of all methods of Query object
    $originalMethods = [];
    foreach ($allOriginalMethods as $method) {
        if (!in_array($method, $skipMethods)) {
            $originalMethods[] = $method;
        }
    }

    $reflection = new \ReflectionClass($originalObject);
    $parentClass = $reflection->getParentClass()->name;

    // Very dummy mock
    $mock = $this
        ->getMockBuilder($parentClass)
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->setMethods($originalMethods)
        ->getMock();

    foreach ($originalMethods as $method) {

        // skip "unmockable"
        if (in_array($method, $skipMethods)) {
            continue;
        }

        // make proxy call to rest of the methods
        $mock
            ->expects($this->any())
            ->method($method)
            ->will($this->returnCallback(
                function (...$args) use ($originalObject, $method, $mock) {
                    $ret = call_user_func_array([$originalObject, $method], $args);

                    // mocking "return $this;" from inside $originalQuery
                    if (is_object($ret) && get_class($ret) == get_class($originalObject)) {
                        if (spl_object_hash($originalObject) == spl_object_hash($ret)) {
                            return $mock;
                        }

                        throw new \Exception(
                            sprintf(
                                'Object [%s] of class [%s] returned clone of itself from method [%s]. Not supported.',
                                spl_object_hash($originalObject),
                                get_class($originalObject),
                                $method
                            )
                        );
                    }

                    return $ret;
                }
            ));
    }

    return $mock;
}
```