# How do I prevent the original method being called when mocking a class with PHPUnit?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

Based on my reading of the PHPUnit documentation, I expect the following code to create a mock of the `AuthorizationChecker` class that will return false when the `isGranted()` method is called. However, the original method is called instead. What am I doing wrong?

```
    $auth = $this->getMockBuilder('Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\AuthorizationChecker')
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->setMethods(['isGranted'])
        ->getMock();
    $auth->expects($this->any())
        ->method('isGranted')
        ->with($this->anything())
        ->will($this->returnValue(false));

    $this->assertFalse($auth->isGranted('TEST'));
```

Replacing the argument to `setMethods()` with null or an empty array, or removing the call entirely, has no effect. Nor does removing the `expects()` and `with()` calls.

Comment: Hi, You can try mocking the AuthorizationCheckerInterface interface that is not finally: depends what you need to do, usually class define as usage the interface of the class.

Comment: Hi Matteo, thanks for the answer and suggestion. I did end up just mocking the interface, which works well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method you are looking to mock is declared as final, so you can't test doubled as described [in the doc](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html):

> **Limitation: final, private, and static methods** 
>   Please note that final,
>   private and static methods cannot be stubbed or mocked. They are
>   ignored by PHPUnit's test double functionality and retain their
>   original behavior.

You can take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32213542/php-mocking-final-class) for a partial solution.

Hope this help

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve this by mocking out all of the internals used by the AuthorizationChecker class and then injecting my mock into the container.

```
    $tokenMock = $this->getMockBuilder( UsernamePasswordToken::class )
                      ->disableOriginalConstructor()
                      ->setMethods( array( 'isAuthenticated' ) )
                      ->getMock();
    $tokenMock->method( 'isAuthenticated' )
              ->willReturn( true );
    $tokenStorageMock = $this->getMockBuilder( TokenStorage::class )
                             ->disableOriginalConstructor()
                             ->setMethods( array( 'getToken' ) )
                             ->getMock();
    $tokenStorageMock->method( 'getToken' )
                     ->willReturn( $tokenMock );
    $authenticationManagerMock = $this->getMockBuilder( AuthenticationManagerInterface::class )
                                      ->disableOriginalConstructor()
                                      ->getMock();
    $accessDecisionManagerMock = $this->getMockBuilder( AccessDecisionManager::class )
                                      ->disableOriginalConstructor()
                                      ->setMethods( array( 'decide' ) )
                                      ->getMock();
    $accessDecisionManagerMock->method( 'decide' )
                              ->willReturn( 'true' );
    $authorizationCheckerMock = $this->getMockBuilder( AuthorizationChecker::class )
                                     ->setConstructorArgs(
                                         array(
                                             $tokenStorageMock,
                                             $authenticationManagerMock,
                                             $accessDecisionManagerMock,
                                             false
                                         )
                                     )
                                     ->setMethods( array( 'isGranted' ) )
                                     ->getMock();
    $authorizationCheckerMock->method( 'isGranted' )
                             ->will( $this->returnValue( true ) );
    $this->getContainer()
         ->set( 'security.authorization_checker', $authorizationCheckerMock );
```