# Argument 1 passed to Class::method() must be an instance of Class, instance of AspectMock\Proxy\ClassProxy given

Tags: php, mocking, phpunit, codeception

So, I am trying to mock a class with `AspectMock::Test`.
I'm running into the issue that the mock is passed as a parameter and when I do this, I get the following error:

```
Argument 1 passed to Foo::spamEggs() must be an instance of Bar, 
instance of AspectMock\Proxy\ClassProxy given
```

The code in question

```
class Foo {
    public function spamEggs(Bar $bar): Egg
    {
        return $bar->getEgg();
    }
}

final class Bar {
    public function getEgg(): Egg
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

The test

```
class TestFoo {
    public function testSpamEggs()
    {
        $bar = Test::double('Bar', [
            'getEgg' => new Egg('green'),
        ]);
        $foo = new Foo();
        $egg = $foo->spamEggs($bar); // throws the error
        $this->assertEquals('green', $egg->colour);
    }
}
```

Is there any way to make this works without me having to remove my parameter typing?

The reason why I moved to AspectMock instead of Stub is that my `Bar` class is `final` and as far as I know, Stub does not support final mocks.

The question is not how I should mock this final class, but what to do about the typed parameter.

Any tips are welcome.

Comment: You could use an implement and use an interface for the type hints instead? Otherwise, remove the `final`?

Comment: Yeah, the final is not really a class of my own, so thats a no. I don't fully understand the reason for the `final` in the first place.. I never used an interface to define the type hinting, I'll look it up.

Comment: If that's not a class you can change then an interface isn't going to help either. Seems they intended for it to always be concrete.

Comment: Ok, I can't answer my own question anymore because it is marked as duplicate.. (Thanks Machavity!)
 .   .  .  . .
I finaly made it work with the use of `Stub::make` and this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50796273/6434747